# Book(s) for Machining Characteristics of Materials

Tags: machining

Peace be upon you all,

Is there a book or handbook which describes the machining characteristics of various engineering materials. For example where I could find data similar to following:

- Material Name: Aluminum
- Hardness Range: X-Y
- Force/ Power Required to machine: A hp

etc.
It is apparent that such data is hard to come by in combined form but still I am hoping for some guidance in this regard.

Regards

Comment: ASM Handbooks have a lot of machining information but not presented  a simple "one size fits all "format.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few handbooks which might cover your needs:

- Handbook of Machining and Metalworking Calculations by Ronald A.Walsh,ISBN: 9780071360661 Publication Date & Copyright: 2001 The McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc.
- Marks' Standard Handbook for Mechanical Engineers, is another more generic but could cover a lot of your questions
- Machinery's Handbook

you can also find a few freely available, eg.  [Garant's machining handbook](https://www.cnc-trainer.com/downloads/garant-machining-handbook.pdf)